# AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down for Mac

Tags: apache, xampp

Apache and MySQL failed to start in XAMPP 7.1.27-1. I got the above error, below is the error log.

```
[Tue Dec 29 10:21:26.460495 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 15627] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Dec 29 10:21:26.467621 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15627] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2r PHP/7.1.27 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 29 10:21:26.467685 2020] [core:notice] [pid 15627] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Fri Jan 15 06:55:08.753700 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15627] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I have used the `lsof -i list` and `kill -9 PROCESS_ID` to kill all processes that run under localhost. I have also changed the apache port, but still apache and MySQL not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is my temporary solution.

1: Edit this file

```
sudo nano /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf
```

2: Add this line, then save the file

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

3: then start MySQL with the below code

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start
```

4: comment the added line in my.cnf, then save the file

```
#innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

5: Stop the MySQL

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server stop
```

6: Use XAMPP Manager to start MySQL

When you restart your PC, you have to repeat these steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -k start
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but the command only start the apache, and in my case, starting the MySQL database is the main concern.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks